# Kafka exactly once with other destination

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Kafka 2 and looks like exactly once is possible with

1. Kafka Streams
2. Kafka read/transform/write transactional producer
3. Kafka connect

Here, all of the above works between topics (source and destination is topic).

Is it possible to have exactly once with other destinations?

Comment: How did you solve the problem? and did you able to get more details around this?

Answer (score 0):

Source and destinations (sinks) of Connect are not only topics, but which Connector you use determines the delivery semantics, not all are exactly once

For example, a JDBC Source Connector polling a database might miss some records

Sink Connectors coming out of Kafka will send every message from a topic, but it's up to the downstream system to acknowledge that retrieval